# The actual building system for D

Tags: build-automation, d

I know there are `DSSS`, `BUD`/build, `Orbit` by Jacob Carlborg and official `rdmd`. And only Orbit seems to be active.
So, which of these is most usable to build huge, complex D programs with many dependencies?
No packaging is needed, just nice and clear build process helper.

Comment: I just created batch files first run with `-c` flag and `-obbin/` and then run the linker on the bin folder

Comment: *.bat/*.sh files - yep, it's working, but something like nice Visual Studio GUI's would be better. The simple plugin for it already exists, and i'm using it. Dreams-dreams :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can create something myself that would handle all dependencies automatically, would allow for multiple main methods compiled in the bin folder and runs specific unittests on demand. but I don't really have the time for that now

Comment: I spent several days working with DSSS/Rebuild, but eventually gave up because of inefficiency and bugs. Its an awesome concept, but if it doesn't keep up with maintenance on dmd then it really isn't worth it. I am currently using makefiles, but on a very small project. I plan to eventually put together a simple build script to manage dependencies, because even rdmd often fails when I get multiple directories involved. It probably is my own fault. I wish rdmd had more documentation.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Deadline on job? Ahh, so many of us _can_ do smth useful, but so few really _do_. Just thoughts. And: do you check Carlborg's `Orbit`?

Comment: @Tim Great thanks for this information! this is what i need. So, you handle all dependencies manually/with scripts too, ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are too, a template for use makefile here: [MakefileForD](https://github.com/bioinfornatics/MakefileForD)

why use it:

- easy to use
- support all compiler
- able to build both shared and static lib or executable
- // build

Answer (score 4):

Not a finished product but....

DMD already has a [-deps flag](http://dlang.org/dmd-linux.html#switches) that should make auto-generating `make` files reasonably simple.

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely argue for [`rdmd`](http://dlang.org/rdmd.html) -- it's a great helper to wrap around your favorite compiler. Basic usage from the docs are:

```
rdmd [rdmd args] [compiler args] <source file>[.d] [executable args]
```

In all of my D projects, I've simply used Bash scripts (with Cygwin if on Windows), and it's worked wonderfully. Here's some of my favorite snippets:

## Run

The whole raison d'être of `rdmd` is to simplify the compile-edit-run cycle to edit-run, and it makes that pretty simple:

```
rdmd helloworld.d [args]
```

`rdmd` won't run any files with a less recent timestamp than the last compile, so next time you run for the same source file without editing it will simply pass through to the previously-compiled executable.

## Select Compiler

Despite the name, you can use most compilers with `rdmd` like GDC, LDC, and DMD like so:

```
rdmd --compiler=dmd ...
```

## Build:

Normally `rdmd` stores the executable and `*.obj` files from your source in a temp directory using `tmpDir()` in `rdmd` source - this is to basically some magic to give `rdmd` the sensation of running `*.d` files as scripts. You can, however, specify the output file with the `-of` flag:

```
rdmd -of"helloworld.exe" helloworld.d
```